# How to apply a map operation in batches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, iteration, list-comprehension

I am using an function that applies object to a list of strings. However, it takes a lot of time to finish, because after checking the object's library website the authors say that you need to apply it by chunks in order to not overload the memory. I am applying the function as follows:

```
list_1 =['hi how are you', 'i am good', ..., 'how is']
results = list(
    map(lambda string_list_elem: foo(string_list_elem, library_obj), list_1))
```

The above is taking too much time. What is the best way to speed up the function application? So far, I tried to split the list in chunks like this:

```
import itertools

def split_seq(iterable, size):
    it = iter(iterable)
    item = list(itertools.islice(it, size))
    while item:
        yield item
        item = list(itertools.islice(it, size))

list(split_seq(list_1, 500))
```

However, I do not know if this will work. Should I do a list comprehension or just use this function and split? What is the recommended way for accelerating the results_list process?

Comment: I'm trying to understand if the problem is that your code is too slow or that traffic to the service is the issue because the server can't be overloaded. In the latter case it seems the problem is inherent and unsolvable. In the former case, you can thread this?

Comment: The problem is not the traffic, this is done locally. The issue is that I must apply the strings in by chunks, and then rejoin them. However, I do not know which is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: many factors to depend on: 1) what's the size of `list-1`? 2) what's the `foo` function doing? 3) what's the network connection speed? 4) *taking to much* - how much is that and what time is acceptable?

Comment: split the list into a list of lists and make foo operate on a list? I don't know the logic appears to be in the foo function.

Comment: the size of `list_1` is `7000`. The function `foo` applies an object to a string. This is done locally, I am not using an api, is just a library. Maybe 15 min, but this is taking more than 1 hour. @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @anon, put clarification on phrase *applies an object to a string* (perhaps share that function code)

Comment: yes @RomanPerekhrest, what I meant to say was that the object transforms a string to another string.

Comment: @anon, post the execution time of a single `foo('hi how are you', library_obj)` call - to get an approximate nominal time

Comment: its 1 second @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: @anon, that's slow. Does it perform I/O operations (side effects), read/write to files/sockets ?

Comment: No, this doesnt have anything to do with networking. All this operations are offline. Thanks

Comment: @anon, read/write to files is not networking but causes I/O

Comment: so why don't you share the function body?

Comment: because its propietary stuff, from my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't show/share the crucial function/worker `foo()` I can't recognize all potential *bottlenecks* to be solved with different optimization techniques.
 
On this phase I would suggest to start with concurrent/asynchronous approach through [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import functools

def foo(string_list_elem, library_obj):
    ....

str_list = ['hi how are you', 'i am good', ..., 'how is']

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # replace `<your_lib>` with your actual library_obj
    results = list(executor.map(functools.partial(foo, library_obj=<your_lib>), str_list))
    print(results)
```

It'll speed up your processing significantly.